# Issues in choices field when deployed to heroku

Tags: django, django-models

I have a model with django-multipleselectfield. It works fine on localhost but when I deploy it to heroku and migrate. It collapses.

added release: python manage.py migrate to Procfile
but doesn't seem to help.

```
class Skill(models.Model):
     SKILL_CHOICES = (
        ('html5', 'HTML5'),
        ('css3-alt', 'CSS3'),
        ('js-square', 'Javascript'),
    )

skills = MultiSelectField(choices=SKILL_CHOICES)
```

error

```
ProgrammingError at /
relation "myself_skill" does not exist
LINE 1: ..."myself_skill"."id", "myself_skill"."skills" FROM "myself_sk...

Exception Type: ProgrammingError
Exception Value:    
relation "myself_skill" does not exist
LINE 1: ..."myself_skill"."id", "myself_skill"."skills" FROM "myself_sk...
```

Comment: Try heroku run python manage.py makemigrations.

Comment: Solved! Took a lot of time but finally fixed. Basically I was querying table before in my view.py before it even existed.